# Where bytecode injection might be useful?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

This year I am going to write a master's thesis in Software Engineering. I am interested in bytecode injection / manipulation in Java. I would like to write some application which might be useful for Java EE developers. Unfortunately I can't find any real use case where bytecode transformations might be usable. I considered writing the fault injector or some mutation testing framework. Sadly, such projects already exist and might not fit thesis requirements (project should be innovative). Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of tools/framework using it, mostly using the annotation processor. Just the ones that came to my mind : [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), [projectlombok](http://projectlombok.org),...

Without annotations, It means that you want to do a tool that can be applied to any programs. For example, a tool that logs all method entries/exits and measure the execution time of all methods.